# XML Validation - If Then

Tags: xml, xslt, xsd, dtd, xsd-validation

I'm trying to find the best way of validating the below XML document. I've looked into three ways of doing this so far:

DTD - doesn't look like there's enough options to make it happen.

XSD - Almost works, but I can't seem to find a way of doing something like If Then

XSL - About the same problem, I can do If's, but I can't seem to figure a way to make it work against this document.

The idea is this: The root element is `<Answers>`. Underneath is 1 or more `<Answer>`. These have an ID attribute marking the question number (handled elsewhere, not important) it corresponds to.
Each question may have 0 or more answers, which are being written now as `<A1>`, `<A2>`...
Each answer has 1 or more elements that go into it, `<E1>`, `<E2>`...

An example document looks like:

```
<Answers>

  <Answer ID="1a">
    <A1>
      <E1>Element 1</E1>
      <E2>Element 2</E2>
      <E3>Element 3</E3>
      <E4>Element 4</E4>
    </A1>
    <A2>
      <E1>Element 1</E1>
      <E2>Element 2</E2>
      <E3>Element 3</E3>
      <E4>Element 4</E4>
    </A2>
  </Answer>

  <Answer ID="1b">
    <A1>
      <E1>Element A</E1>
      <E2>Element B</E2>
      <E3>Element C</E3>
    </A1>
  </Answer>

  <Answer ID="2">
    <A1>
      <E1>Element 1</E1>
      <E2>Element 2</E2>
      <E3>Element 3</E3>
      <E4>Element 4</E4>
      <E5>Element 5</E5>
    </A1>
    <A2>
      <E1>Element 1</E1>
      <E2>Element 2</E2>
      <E3>Element 3</E3>
      <E4>Element 4</E4>
      <E5>Element 5</E5>
    </A2>
    <A3>
      <E1>Element 1</E1>
      <E2>Element 2</E2>
      <E3>Element 3</E3>
      <E4>Element 4</E4>
      <E5>Element 5</E5>
    </A3>

  </Answer>
</Answers>
```

What goes into the Elements is any string, the content is not important, as long is it is not empty.

What I need to validate for is that for each Answer (denoted by ID), for each `<A*>`, that there is a certain amount of elements. In this example, 1a has 4 elements, 1b has 3, and 2 has 5.

The format is flexible, so if need be I can change things to something like:
        
          Element A
          Element B
          Element C
        
or something along those lines.

I've tried all sorts of combinations with this, but I can't seem to find a way of requiring X amount of `<E*>`'s depending on Answer ID.

Does anyone have any thoughts, or can they point me in the right direction, even if it's just saying "Yes, XSD can do this", or "No, XSL cannot do this"?

Comment: XSLT transforms documents - it does not validate them. You _can_ write a transformation that points you towards elements that do not satisfy your constraints - but you could not call that "validation". Would that be an option for you? If not, no, DTD cannot do that. Your options for validation languages are: XML Schema, RelaxNG and Schematron would also be capable of that (and the easiest!).

Comment: Another option, the first one that popped into my mind, is XQuery.

Comment: DTD cannot do it.   XSD 1.0 cannot do it.   XSD 1.1 can do it with assertions.   XSLT can do it by parsing the ID and counting child elements.      So, pick your poison.  ;-)

Comment: Also: What are the rules, exactly? Is there a finite set of `A*` elements? Do you know in advance how many child elements each of them has or are those numbers computed somehow? Does the number of child elements somehow depend on the attribute value?

Comment: @Mathias Müller
There can be 1 or more of the A elements under each Answer element.
I will know in advance the numbers later on, but for this example, just assume: >= 1 A for each Answer, and 4 E's under Answer ID="1a", 3 under ID="1b", and 5 under ID="2"

Comment: "*In this example, 1a has 4 elements,*" Actually, in this example, 1a has 8 elements. But still, you *could* write an XSLT to "validate" that each child of `<Answer ID="1a">` has exactly 4 child elements of its own, or that it has exactly the elements listed. And, if you wanted, you could keep  the requirements in an external XML document, so you could change that from time to time without having to modify the XSLT.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The type of validation you'd like to do (an "if then" statement) is called *assertion*. As pointed out by @kjhughes, XML Schema 1.1 has assertions and you could implement such complex relationships in the XML document with XSD 1.1.

Alternatively, you could use an XSLT transformation that does not really perform validation, but, in a way, transforms your input XML into only the cases where your constraints are not satisfied. Still, XSLT is not a validation language.

I assume someone is eventually going to contribute an XSLT answer - so I would like to suggest something else: [Schematron](http://www.schematron.com/). The following Schematron rules are assertions that define exactly the constraints you need.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<schema xmlns="http://purl.oclc.org/dsdl/schematron" queryBinding="xslt2">

    <pattern>
        <title>Content of the answer element.</title>
        <rule context="Answer">
            <assert test="*[starts-with(name(),'A')]" xml:lang="en">The <name/> element must contain at least 1 A* element.</assert>
        </rule>
    </pattern>

    <pattern>
        <title>Count number of child elements E* of elements A*</title>
        <rule context="Answer[@ID = '1a']/*[starts-with(name(),'A')]">
            <assert test="count(*[starts-with(name(),'E')]) = 4" xml:lang="en">If the @ID attribute of the Answer element is "1a",
                then all child elements A* must have exactly 4 child elements E*.</assert>
        </rule>
        <rule context="Answer[@ID = '1b']/*[starts-with(name(),'A')]">
            <assert test="count(*[starts-with(name(),'E')]) = 3" xml:lang="en">If the @ID attribute of the Answer element is "1b",
                then all child elements A* must have exactly 3 child elements E*.</assert>
        </rule>
        <rule context="Answer[@ID = '2']/*[starts-with(name(),'A')]">
            <assert test="count(*[starts-with(name(),'E')]) = 5" xml:lang="en">If the @ID attribute of the Answer element is "2",
                then all child elements A* must have exactly 5 child elements E*.</assert>
        </rule>
    </pattern>

</schema>
```

If the input document contains the following structure:

```
<Answer ID="1a">
    <A1>
        <E1>Element 1</E1>
        <E2>Element 2</E2>
        <E4>Element 4</E4>
    </A1>
</Answer>
```

the validating application would complain, saying that

```
E [ISO Schematron] If the @ID attribute of the Answer element is "1a", then all child elements A* must have exactly 4 child elements E*.
```

Schematron files can be interpreted with the [Schematron Reference Implementation](http://www.schematron.com/implementation.html) - an XSLT stylesheet - or environments like Oxygen.

---

Aside note: It would not be too difficult to translate the SCH rules above to XSLT, because they are very similar. You'd have to replace the following, for instance:

```
SCH                                 | XSLT equivalent
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
<sch:rule context="...">            | <xsl:template match="...">
<sch:assert test="*">               | <xsl:if test="not(*)">
<sch:report test="*">               | <xsl:if test="*">
```

Comment: Thanks, Mathias...
Looking at this, it would work perfectly. The only problem is that my Schematron is not an option with what I'm trying, or with my organization.

In the end, this is will be an XmlDocument in VB.Net that I want to validate before putting into a database. It does look like assertions are the way to go, though.

Comment: @neilsimp1 All you need is an XSLT processor - and since you mentioned XSLT as a possible solution in your question, I assumed that you can process XSLT stylesheets.